# Rubberduck is growing out of SE chat

Tags: support, status-completed, meta, chat

At one point in time, the *VBA Rubberducking* chat was CR's most active chat room. Here we are almost a whole decade later, and Rubberduck as a project is entering a new phase as work on version 3.0 is starting.

SE chat was the perfect home for Rubberduck at the time: we had a feed of VBA posts on CR, VBA questions on SO would show up in a little ticker, and @Duga would tell us everything going on in the GitHub repository.

As a moderator I had quick access to CR and everything Rubberduck, it was perfect.

Meanwhile Rubberduck has become essentially the defacto VBIDE add-in you need for VBA, and the next step would be to expand to a broader audience - and that's where SE chat is no longer useful. Building version 3.0 will demand much tighter planning, and GitHub is helping with this a lot, but in order to reach broader communities and keep growing, the time has come for Rubberduck to move on from SE chat.

I've pinned a link to Rubberduck's new [Discord server](https://discord.gg/MYX9RECenJ) (feel free to join!) in the chat room, but pins eventually expire, and with @Duga regularly posting (I'll deactivate the GitHub webhooks soon) it's unlikely the room will freeze all by itself as the system intended.

So this is it, we've packed our bags and we're at the doorstep waving goodbye with teary eyes and nostalgia, and the cab is honking. We'll never forget where we came from: Code Review SE is always going to be a part of Rubberduck's history.

I hereby formally request for the [VBA Rubberducking](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba-rubberducking) chatroom to be frozen and archived. See y'all on Discord!

Comment: Sniff... sniff... Don't forget to call your mother!

Comment: Discord link works here but not the one at https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Done.

Rubberduck played a big role in the history of Code Review. If the links ever change, make sure you update your question so people can still find the way.